# Boa tarde, precisava de ajuda para uma calculadora em c++

Tags: c++

Fiz este programa para calcular áreas e perímetros de formas geométricas, mas quando pressiono "a", "b" ou "c" para escolher se queres fazer áreas ou perímetros o programa apenas fecha. Segue o código:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <locale> 
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
  
    double PerimetroQuadrado (double Lado) {
        return 4 * Lado;
    }
    double AreaQuadrado (double Lado) {
        return Lado * Lado;
    }
    double PerimetroRetangulo (double Comprimento, double Altura) {
        return Comprimento*2 + Altura*2;
    }
    double AreaRetangulo (double Comprimento, double Altura) {
        return Comprimento * Altura;
    }
    double PerimetroCirculo (double Raio) {
        return 2 * M_PI * Raio;
    }
    double AreaCirculo (double Raio) {
        return M_PI * pow(Raio,2);
    }
    double PerimetroTriangulo (double Base, double Altura) {
        double hipotenusa = hypot(Base , Altura);
        return Base + Altura + hipotenusa;
    }
    double AreaTriangulo (double Base, double Altura) {
        return Base * Altura / 2;
    }
    double PerimetroTrapezio (double BaseMaior, double BaseMenor, double Altura) {
        double Hipotenusa = hypot((BaseMaior - BaseMenor) / 2 , Altura);
        return BaseMenor + BaseMaior + 2 * Hipotenusa;
    }
    double AreaTrapezio (double BaseMaior, double BaseMenor, double Altura) {
        return (BaseMenor + BaseMaior) * Altura / 2;
    }
    
    int main (){
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
      
        cout << "Cálculo de Perímetros e Áreas. \n";
        cout << "Escolha uma das seguintes opcões: \n";
        cout << "\t a- Perímetro \n";
        cout << "\t b- Área \n";
        cout << "\t c- Sair \n";
        
        
        int num1 , num2 , num3; 
        char op;
        cin >> op;
        char pr;
        char ar;
        switch(op){
             case 'a': 
             case 'A': 
             break;
             cout << "Cálculo de Perímetros e Áreas. \n";
             cout << "Escolha uma das seguintes opcões: \n";
             cout << "\t 1- Quadrado \n";
             cout << "\t 2- Retângulo \n";
             cout << "\t 3- Círculo \n";
             cout << "\t 4- Triângulo Retângulo \n";
             cout << "\t 5- Trapézio \n";
             cout << "\t 6- Voltar \n";
             cout << "\t 7- Sair \n";
             cin >> pr;
                switch(pr) {
                case '1': cout << "Introduza o Valor do Lado do Quadrado:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << PerimetroQuadrado(num1);
                          break;
                case '2': cout << "Introduza o Valor do Comprimento do Retângulo:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Altura do Retângulo:";
                          cin >> num2;
                          cout << PerimetroRetangulo(num1, num2);
                          break;
                case '3': cout << "Introduza o Valor do Raio do Círculo:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << PerimetroCirculo(num1);
                          break;
                case '4': cout << "Introduza o Valor da Base do Triângulo:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Altura do Triângulo:";
                          cin >> num2;
                          cout << PerimetroTriangulo(num1, num2);
                          break;
                case '5': cout << "Introduza o Valor da Base Maior do Trapézio:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Base Menor do Trapézio:";
                          cin >> num2;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Altura do Trapézio:";
                          cin >> num3;
                          cout << PerimetroTrapezio(num1, num2 , num3);
                          break;
                case '6': 
                break;
                }
        
             case 'b': 
             case 'B': 
             break;
             cout << "Cálculo de Perímetros e Áreas. \n";
             cout << "Escolha uma das seguintes opcões: \n";
             cout << "\t 1- Quadrado \n";
             cout << "\t 2- Retângulo \n";
             cout << "\t 3- Círculo \n";
             cout << "\t 4- Triângulo Retângulo \n";
             cout << "\t 5- Trapézio \n";
             cout << "\t 6- Voltar \n";
             cout << "\t 7- Sair \n";
             cin >> ar;
              switch(ar) {
              case '1': cout << "Introduza o Valor do Lado do Quadrado:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << AreaQuadrado(num1);
                          break;
                case '2': cout << "Introduza o Valor do Comprimento do Retângulo:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Altura do Retângulo:";
                          cin >> num2;
                          cout << AreaRetangulo(num1, num2);
                          break;
                case '3': cout << "Introduza o Valor do Raio do Círculo:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << AreaCirculo(num1);
                          break;
                case '4': cout << "Introduza o Valor da Base do Triângulo:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Altura do Triângulo:";
                          cin >> num2;
                          cout << AreaTriangulo(num1, num2);
                          break;
                case '5': cout << "Introduza o Valor da Base Maior do Trapézio:";
                          cin >> num1;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Base Menor do Trapézio:";
                          cin >> num2;
                          cout << "Introduza o Valor da Altura do Trapézio:";
                          cin >> num3;
                          cout << AreaTrapezio(num1, num2 , num3);
                          break;
                case '7': exit (0);
                break;
                
              case 'c':
              case 'C': exit (0);
              break;
              default: cout << "Inválido";
              break;
              }
    
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Você está fazendo `break` logo ao entrar nas condições `a`/`A` e `b`/`B` do switch. Isso interrompe a execução do switch de imediato, antes de rodar a sua lógica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo pois logo após entrar nas condições do seu `switch case` você está dando um `break`:

```cpp
...
switch(op){
             case 'a': 
             case 'A': 
        >>>  break;
...
```

A função do `break` é justamente sair de uma instrução (no seu caso, o `switch case`) e ir para outra. Como seu código não tem mais nenhuma instrução após o `switch case` (um `for`, ou um `while`, ou até mesmo outro `switch`, etc) ele é encerrado.

Para resolver o problema basta retirar estes `breaks` que estão logo após as condições do `switch` (tanto do case `a` quanto do `b`).